# Como obtener valores con select y que muestre y se repita n cantidad en la misma fila de la tabla, Javascript

Tags: javascript

El objetivo de lo que necesito es algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> En una tabla en `html` generar una fila donde se agregue un `select` y ese `select` tenga 3 `option`, y que según el `option` seleccionado, 
>   me genere el resto de la fila (que en teoría serian columnas) con el valor que elegí en el `select`, y el valor que se repite debe ser el mismo.

**Lo que tengo hasta ahora:**

```js
function selector_a() {
 var valor1 = 100;
 var valor2 = 200;
 var maximo = 5
 var contador = 0
 var cadena = `<tr>
                    <td> 
                        <select id="select_opcion_${contador}" onchange="OpcionChange('select_opcion_${contador}', 'select_escoger_${contador}')"> 
                            <option value="0">Valor 0</option>
                            <option value="${valor1}">Valor 1</option>
                            <option value="${valor2}">Valor 2</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>`
            for (let i = 0; i <= maximo; i++) {
                cadena += `<td id="select_escoger_${contador}">${OpcionChange(contador)}</td> `
                contador++
            }
    cadena += `</tr>`
    document.getElementById('numeros_repetidos').innerHTML = cadena;
    }
    selector_a()

    function OpcionChange(contador) {
       var cadena = `<input  class="text-center" type="number" value="${contador}" readonly></input></td>`
       return cadena;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
<thead >
  <tr>
      <th>Select</th>
      <th colspan="6">Valores</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="numeros_repetidos"></tbody>
</table>
```

> en el código estoy usando un contador para que se generen los `td` con el "valor" que se supone se elige y se debe repetir y parar hasta cumplir la condición en el `for` con la variable `maximo`.